# Extract specific values from cells from a CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

I have to combine a lot of files , mostly CSV, already have code  to combine however I need first to trim the desired csv files so I can get the data that I want.  Each CSV has first 2 columns of 8 rows which contain data that I want. and then just below those there is a row that generates 8 columns.  I am only having issue grabbing data from the first 8 rows of the 2 columns.

Example of the csv first 3 rows:

```
Target Name:        MIAW
Target OS:          Windows
Last Updated On:    June 27 2019 07:35:11
```

This is the data that I want, the first 3 rows are like this, with 2 columns. My idea is to store the 3 values of the 2nd column each into a variable and then use it with the rest of my code.

As I only have a problem extracting the data, and since the way the CSV are formated there is no header at all, it is hard to come up with an easy way to read the 2nd column data.  Below is an example, this of course will be used to process several files so it will be a `foreach`, but I want to come up first with the simple code for 1 file so I can adapt it myself to a `foreach`.

```
$a = MIAW-Results-20190627T203644Z.csv
Write-Host "$a[1].col2"
```

This would work if and only if I had a header called col2, I could name it with the first value on the 2nd column but the issue is that that value will change for CSV file. So the code I tried would not work for example if I were to import several files using:

```
$InFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot\ *.csv -File |
           Where-Object Name -like *results*
```

Each CSV will have a different value for the first value on the 2nd column.

Is there an easier way to just grab the 3 rows of the second column that I need? I need to grab each one and store each in a different variable.

Comment: Looks like you have a very messy CSV, so why don't you show some relevant part of it so we know what we're up against?

Comment: its a set of csv, each one has different data, but I am only interested on the first 3 rows , with the problem being that as there are no headers, the first row on the 2nd column will be changing values and I want the 3 first rows of that 2nd column. Also let me edit my question, for some reason on the formatting when posting it changed the example of the csv.

Comment: The variable `$a[1].col2` won't expand like you'd expect when you convert it to a string. Use `Write-Host "$($a[1].col2)"`

Comment: @VictorJMytre - the data you show IS NOT A VALID  CSV FILE. [*grin*] no matter what the extension may be, that is not a Comma Separated Value file. ///// take a look at the `ConvertFrom-String*` cmdlets for ways to convert that sort of plain text string collection into PoSh objects.